# How to create a TextField in Vaadin flow (Vaadin 14) Grid that could write back in ValueChangeEvent ? (not using Grid Editor)

Tags: vaadin, vaadin14

I am trying to put TextField as Editable component in each row of Grid.
but I don't know how to write back in the ValueChange event ?

below is my code

```
    SerializableBiConsumer<emisTextField, PO_DETL_GRID> consumer =
        (tf , detl) ->{ 
            tf.setValue( detl.getP_NO());               
    } ; 
    SerializableSupplier<emisTextField> ss = () -> {
        emisTextField tf =new emisTextField();
        tf.addValueChangeListener(c->{
        
            //how to write back newValue to my PO_DETL_GRID item ?
                
        });
        return tf;
    };
    ComponentRenderer cr = new ComponentRenderer<emisTextField,PO_DETL_GRID>(ss,consumer);
    
    Grid.Column p_no_column = edit_grid.addColumn( cr);
    
    grid.addColumn(cr);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use this alternative constructor:

```
SerializableFunction<MyItem, TextField> function = item -> {
    TextField tf = new TextField();
    tf.setValue(item.getMyValue());
    tf.addValueChangeListener(e -> item.setMyValue(e.getValue()));
    return tf;
};
ComponentRenderer<TextField, MyItem> cr = new ComponentRenderer<>(function);
```

Comment: thanks a lot. my working version.

  SerializableFunction<PO_DETL_GRID, emisTextField> function = item -> {
   emisTextField tf = new emisTextField();
      tf.setValue( item.getP_NO());
      tf.addValueChangeListener(e -> {
       item.setP_NO(tf.getValue()); 
      });
      return tf;
  };