# Vaadin Flow How to control focus TextField in Grid?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid

As my [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67582078/how-to-create-a-textfield-in-vaadin-flow-vaadin-14-grid-that-could-write-back)

```
SerializableFunction<MyItem, TextField> function = item -> {
TextField tf = new TextField();
tf.setValue(item.getMyValue());
tf.addValueChangeListener(e -> item.setMyValue(e.getValue()));
return tf;
};
ComponentRenderer<TextField, MyItem> cr = new ComponentRenderer<>(function);
```

I found another problem  that I found no way to indicate focus of textField on SelectChange event of Grid.

I found that when add a new record , the SelectChange event is prior to the create of textField.

and seems vaadin has no Row Concept ?

Answer (score 2):

First thought that springs to mind: add a class variable that keeps track of the latest selected item (updated when the selection change listener is triggered), and check your `item` against that in your `function`. (And maybe also another class variable for saving the previously styled TextField, so that you can remove the selection styling too.)

Comment: I would recommend to use integrated editor of the Grid instead of component renderer if possible. With it you can control the focus better, like in this example https://cookbook.vaadin.com/grid-with-map

Comment: thank you!
but I am not the guy that could determine our operation style. 
I auto focus the textFields on ComponentRender.
and put textFields to Item Map for later operation.
it seems to work fine.